# Unable to Lazy load Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

Well I am unable to lazy load images for some reason. Here is the [waterfall view](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/chT4z7/http://geniushowto.blogspot.com) of the tested site

Apparently I am using two lazy load scripts with [lazy load script 1](http://jsfiddle.net/geniusknight/ykrj7c8d/) which works but kills the lightbox plugin and also requires lots of tweaking using data-src and src and class="lazy-load" attributes. which I am using for non post related images.

But the main problem lies in the second script which requires Jquery but doesn't require any tweaking with the images. The script is called `stalactite` (via Github) which I am using like this

```
<script charset='utf-8' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript' />
<script href='http://googledrive.com/host/0B2xMFcMT-eLiV1owdlBMeklGc2M' type='text/javascript' />
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $( &#39;body&#39;).stalactite({
        loader: &#39;<img/>&#39; // The contents of the loader. Defaults to a dataURL animated gif.
    });
</script>
```

You can find the link of the stalactite script in the above code and here is the [documentation](http://jonobr1.github.io/stalactite/). 
I don't know why it doesn't work ! Or am I executing it wrongly. 
A solution to the problem will be very helpful. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does HTML encoding even *work* inside of script tags?  Never seen that before.

Comment: That's just XML parsing and yes I guess html encoding does work inside script tags. http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=5f64b3edd0f2a6b3d9bbf10d3cf27d2f

Answer (score -1):

If you are tired of trying to use lazy load libraries and haven't managed to make all of it work, I can suggest you to create lazy load script on your own, or you can take a look at this code below.

By only using jQuery and without needing any other library, you can use this script to achieve the lazy load (I modified the codes from the original one that I used at work):

```
var doLazyLoad = true;
var lazyLoadCounter = 0;
var lazyLoadMax = 2;    // Maximum number of lazy load done

// Button to indicate lazy load is loading, 
// or when lazy load has reached its maximum number, 
// this button load data manually.
// You can replace this with something like gif loading animation.
var $btnLoadMore = $("#btn-lazy-load-more");

// I use AJAX function to get the data on lazy load
var ajaxFn = function (enableScrollAnim = true) {
    var loadingStr = 'Loading...',
        idleStr = 'Load more',
        ajaxUrl = 'http://www.example.com/posts',
        ajaxHeaders = {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        ajaxData = {
            start: $('.posts-wrapper .post').length
        };

    $btnLoadMore.text(loadingStr);  // You can disable the button to prevent manual loading

    return $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ajaxData,
        headers: ajaxHeaders,

        // On success AJAX, append newly loaded data to lazy load container.
        // Here in my example, the GET request returns data.view i.e. the content, and data.total i.e. total number of posts
        success: function (data) {
            var $newLoadedPosts = $(data.view),
                nlsMarginBottom;

            $('.posts-wrapper').append($newLoadedPosts);
            $newLoadedPosts.css('display', 'none').fadeIn();

            // Animate auto scroll to newly loaded content
            if (enableScrollAnim) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $newLoadedPosts.first().offset().top
                });
            }

            if ($('.posts-wrapper .post').length < data.total) {
                $btnLoadMore.text(idleStr);  // If you disable the button, enable the button again here
            } else {
                // Remove the button when there's no more content to load.
                // Determined by data.total
                $btnLoadMore.remove(); 
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $btnLoadMore.text(idleStr);  // If you disable the button, enable the button again here
        }
    });
};

// Do the lazy load here
if ($btnLoadMore.length) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollOffset = (($btnLoadMore.offset().top - $(window).height()) + $btnLoadMore.height()) + 100;
        var hasReachedOffset = $(window).scrollTop() >= scrollOffset;
        var isLmsBtnExist = $btnLoadMore.length;

        if (hasReachedOffset && lazyLoadCounter < lazyLoadMax && doLazyLoad && isLmsBtnExist) {
            doLazyLoad = false;

            ajaxFn(false).always(function () {
                doLazyLoad = true;
                lazyLoadCounter++;
            });
        }
    });
}

$btnLoadMore.click(ajaxFn);
```

And here is the [GIF demo image](https://giphy.com/gifs/demo-lazy-load-l3q2MmEAZJmH8zHu8) of my working code.

If you need any further explanation, just comment this answer and I will try to help you.